# Can't get login call back with Facebook SDK swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to login to facebook with facebook sdk but when user authorized the app, it shows blank screen like this and can't get callback.
It used to work fine, but suddenly, it doesn't work.

[image: Here's screenshot.]

```
    let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    manager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login cancelled")
        }
        else {
            let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(token)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
                else {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MainScreenSignUp", sender: self)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Is there anybody who has experience in this area?

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck by the same, it is due to the property **"loginBehavior"** of the **"FBSDKLoginManager"**, i get it working using: `manager.loginBehavior = .Web`
By default it uses the **".Native"** that gets the result you posted.

Hope it helps!

Excuse my english!